# Can't return Salesforce MAP<String, Object> using get

Tags: maps, salesforce

I have this code:

```apex
Map<String, Account> Map_Account = new Map<String,Account>( [SELECT Name,Id
                                                            FROM Account 
                                                            WHERE name = 'Any Company Name']);

System.debug('------Task Map List------' + Map_Task_Frequency);
System.debug('*****Task Map*****' + Map_Task_Frequency.get('Any Company Name'));
```

In Workbench I get the following results which I also get in while coding in Salesforce:

```
DEBUG|------Task Map List------{001g0000005PCWbAAO=Account:{Name=Any Company Name,
DEBUG|*****Task Map*****null
```

Can anyone tell why when I pass the string value in a Map it returns Null even though there is clearly an account in the Map?

Help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that key of your map is Id, is not String, you can see it from first debug message.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for your use case what Pavel described is totally true
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps_from_SObjects.htm

for your code to work the way you wanted to it has to be rewritten

```
Map<String, Account> Map_Task_Frequency = new Map<String,Account>();
for(Account a:  [SELECT Name,Id
                        FROM Account 
                        WHERE name = 'Any Company Name'] ){
  Map_Task_Frequency.put(a.Name, a);
}

System.debug('------Task Map List------' + Map_Task_Frequency);
System.debug('*****Task Map*****' + Map_Task_Frequency.get('Any Company Name'));
```

which won't make much sense as you'll be referencing your account record by name and that is on your WHERE condition so you'll end up with only one value on your map containing the last account loaded.